# VBA macro to find duplicates and keep larger value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a little lost where to begin in solving the problem.

Data set:

```
AAA15200    12A    60
AAA15200    12B    60
AAA15200    12C    60
AAA15200    13A    60
AAA15200    13A    70
AAA15200    12A    65
```

Problem:

Column 1 would be a product code.
 I need to find per product a duplicate in column 2.

 If a duplicate occurs in column two, i need to go to column 3 and find which is the lesser value, and delete row of lesser value.

So in the above data set - AAA15200 has a duplicate of 13A. The bottom duplicate has 70 which is greater than 60, so i want to delete the row with contains 60. 
Bottom line also is duplicate with the top row, yet bottom row has 65 which is greater than 60. so delete top row.

Row a will then change to a new product code which the same would need to occur for it.
[this is for work, if no solution found we'll have to go through manually for 9,000+ rows]

Comment: You don't need VBA for this if you are prepared to use some helper columns. try and work out how to split the data into columns and how to write an array formula for Maxif. Post back where you get to and we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pertinent to your question, the task can be achieved by using VBA macro or just Excel worksheet functions, or just elementary data operations as described below. Assuming you have initial data set in columns A, B and C:

```
A           B   C
AAA15200    12A 60
AAA15200    12B 60
AAA15200    12C 60
AAA15200    13A 60
AAA15200    13A 70
AAA15200    12A 65
```

first, sort it on Column C in descending order resulting in the following:

```
A           B   C
AAA15200    13A 70
AAA15200    12A 65
AAA15200    12A 60
AAA15200    12B 60
AAA15200    12C 60
AAA15200    13A 60
```

then apply the "Remove Duplicates" data operation on Columns A, B to get the final:

```
A           B   C   
AAA15200    13A 70
AAA15200    12A 65
AAA15200    12B 60
AAA15200    12C 60
```

Hope this may help. Best regards,

Comment: Seems to work really well. Is there a way of finding out what it removes?

Comment: I am glad it works for you. Please  mark the answer accepted if you are satisfied with the solution. Should you have more questions, please post them separately (pertinent to the one you've asked in comments: there are many different ways to accomplish that, for example using the Excel Filters, or VLOOKUP functions comparing the original (cashed somewhere) and final lists, or by using VBA, etc). Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed by [Alex Bell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/979580/alex-bell) is the correct method. If this is a procedure that is often repeated then you may mirror the method described in VBA.

While this method could easily be recorded for later use via the [macro recorder](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Step-1-Start-with-the-macro-recorder-6DC53056-1DE1-4483-AA07-63E4E0EFE3C2), the code it would produce for the [Range.Sort method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840646.aspx) is very verbose. This should be all that you need.

```
with worksheets("Sheet1")
    with .cells(1, 1).currentregion
        .cells.sort key1:=.columns(3), order1:=xldescending
                    orientation:=xltoptobottom, header:=xlyes
        .removeduplicates columns:=array(1, 2), header:=xlyes
    end with
end with
```

That looks about right. Check the docs on the [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx) to make sure that range reference is going to accommodate your needs. Similarly, the [Range.RemoveDuplicates method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193823.aspx) and [Range.Sort method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840646.aspx) have additional options that can be implemented.

Comment: using the above code, is there a way of outputting the removed rows to somewhere to use it to valid data?

Comment: No, the [Range.RemoveDuplicates method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193823.aspx) permanently remove the duplicate entries. What you are looking for might be closer to the [Advanced Filter](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Video-Advanced-filter-details-BBD0CB0A-8F90-43DF-BF77-6AD3774DC420) method. However, this new wrinkle breaks the answers to the original question and should be posed as a new question lest this become a [Russian Doll Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188625/etiquette-for-russian-doll-questions).

Answer (score 0):

Enter the formula below as an array formula (using Ctrl+Shift+Enter) and fill down.
Copy-paste values then delete the rows with TRUE

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sort every column from smallest to biggest. 
In the helper column Formula=--((a1&b1) =(a2&b2)) 
Filter helper column on 1 and select special cells visible cells only, delete every row. 
This works perfectly with your sample data. The smallest value from 2 values is deleted  I suspect things might be more complicated, Let me know. 
Have a good  day.